# Error one or more parameters is required

Tags: c#, oledb

This is C# code and giving me an error that one or more parameters are required in the access database can anyone help me?...I am hanged due to this error!

Here's the code:

```
string date = textBox1.Text; 
con = new OleDbConnection(cs); 
con.Open();        
String sql = "SELECT * From Sales where InvoiceDate = date "; 
cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: string date = textBox1.Text;
                con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
                con.Open();
                String sql = "SELECT * From Sales where InvoiceDate = date ";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: Please [edit] and improve your question. Also please *study* the [help] and the [ask] to see what is expected in questions posted to this site.

Comment: `String sql = "SELECT * From Sales where InvoiceDate = date "; ` the `date` part in the string doesn't have anything to do with your `date` variable. You need to add a parameter.

Comment: You need to research how to use parameters. `where InvoiceDate = date` won't magically pass the `date` variable's value

Comment: Why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` when you correctly call `ExecuteReader` latter?

Comment: Date Have a Value String Please Specify me That How I will Correct the error

Comment: @Rich Ugh, no, just no.  They should use a parameter instead.  First off that won't put the required single quotes around the date and second you cannot be sure it uses the correct format.

Comment: Any One Write a code for me that how i will pass date variable from query

Comment: @AsadKhan Is `InvoiceDate` an actual date type in your DB?  If so I'd suggest parsing the string date to a `DateTime` and then using the result as a parameter.  If not, it really should be.

Comment: error is in ExecuteNonQuery and also give me error by ExecuteReader

Comment: I Think You all Are developer like me If Your then write code that will fix my issue its just 4-5 line code

Comment: @AsadKhan,check out my answer .. It will help you understand :)

Comment: @AsadKhan , did u solve ur issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I recommend parsing that date to a `DateTime` as I hope your `InvoiceDate` is an actual date type in the DB.  Second you need to use a parameter to pass in the value.  Finally remove that `ExecuteNonQuery`.  Also you should put disposable items into using statements so the connection will be closed properly.

```
DateTime date;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out date))
{
    //Do whatever you need to indicate a bad date.
}

using(var con = new OleDbConnection(cs))
{
    con.Open();        
    String sql = "SELECT * From Sales where InvoiceDate = @date"; 
    using(var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", /*Insert correct type here*/).Value = date;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()); 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
    }
}
```

Comment: is the OP even active ?? feel bad now for posting a huge answer :(

Answer (score 0):

**First flaw** : You didn't mention what `cs` is(i mean show us the connection string) but not much of a big issue as it is not throwing the error.

**Second flaw** : `InvoiceDate = date` , here `date` is neither a value nor a variable.

**To use it as a variable**

```
 ...InvoiceDate ='" + date + "'"
```

**To use it as direct value**

```
 ...InvoiceDate ='date'"
```

**Third Flaw** : `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` , it is unnecessary.

**Fourth flaw** : Well, i shouldn't call it a flaw,rather a bit of knowledge sharing : You can create a separate `DataAdapter` and then use it to populate your table :

```
 OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
 ada.Fill(mydatatable);
```

**Biggest flaw** : `Sql-Injection` , please don't make it easy for attackers.Rather use `parameters`:

```
 "SELECT * From Sales where InvoiceDate=@date"
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Varchar).Vale = dateStringHere ///change data-type from varchar as required
```

Comment: One would hope that a column called `InvoiceDate` is not stored as a `varchar`

Comment: @juharr , i hope my answer is ideal to describe the OP about his issues and gives him pre-cautions.And bout the date-time,i did add side comment to notify OP that he can change the dataType as required and if he understands that, he can surely do the `DateTime` parse/convert thing :) ... Hope u understand :)